# Background image set wrong by firefox and ie

Tags: background, background-image, quotes

ive been working on a page builder and have run into this double quote problem.

`div id="set" style="color:black;font-size:12px"`

`document.getElementById('set').style.backgroundImage="url('editor.png')"`

or

`document.getElementById('set').style.backgroundImage="url(editor.png)"`

This sets in firefox and IE

`div id="set" style="url("editor.png");color:black;font-size:12px"`

When The page is saved and reloaded the double quotes break up the style.

Does anyone know a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is here - **url("editor.png")**

```
<div id="set" style="url("editor.png");color:black;font-size:12px">
```

try this

```
<div id="set" style="background-image :url('editor.png');color:black;font-size:12px">
```